# Count do cursor retorna mais valores porém só adiciona um item na lista

Tags: java, android

Estou consultando uma tabela de Clientes, estou selecionando tudo afim de teste, porém o que está acontecendo é que ao jogar a query no cursor e dar um getCount ele retorna **4** como esperado, porém ao dar um moveToFirst a position vai para **0**, tudo bem, adiciono certinho, ao dar o moveToNext a posição do cursor vai para 3 ai termina o loop de adição de obj na lista, abaixo segue os Fontes:

**Metodo que Retorna a lista:**

```
public ArrayList<Cliente> getClienteByCpfCnpj2() {
    Cliente cliente;
    ArrayList<Cliente> lista = new ArrayList<Cliente>();

    cursor = null;
    database = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = database.query(CriaBanco.TABELA_CLIENTE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
        do {
            cliente = getClienteById(cursor.getInt(0));
            cliente.setLinha1(cliente.getNome());
            lista.add(cliente);
            cursor.moveToNext();
            int a = cursor.getPosition();
            int b = cursor.getCount();
        } while (cursor.isLast());
    cursor.close();
    return lista;
}
```

**Metodo getClienteById:**

```
public Cliente getClienteById(int idCliente) {
    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    database = banco.getReadableDatabase();
    try {
        cursor = database.rawQuery(
                " SELECT c._Id, c.IdGrupoEmpresa, c.Nome, c.NomeFantasia, c.TipoPessoa, C.CpfCnpj," +
                        "       e._Id ,e.TipoEnd,e.EndCliente, e.ComplEnd,e.Numero,e.Cep, e.IdCliente, e.IdBairro," +
                        "       b._Id, b.Nome," +
                        "       m._Id, m.Nome, m.CodIbge," +
                        "       est._Id, est.Nome, est.Sigla" +
                        " FROM Cliente c" +
                        " LEFT JOIN Endereco e on (e.IdCliente = c._Id)" +
                        " LEFT JOIN Bairro b on (e.IdBairro = b._Id)" +
                        " LEFT JOIN Municipio m on (b.IdMunicipio = m._Id)" +
                        " LEFT JOIN Estado est on (m.IdEstado = est._Id)" +
                        " WHERE c._Id =" + idCliente, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            cliente.setId(cursor.getInt(0));
            cliente.setIdGrupoEmpresa(cursor.getInt(1));
            cliente.setNome(cursor.getString(2));
            cliente.setNomeFantasia(cursor.getString(3));
            cliente.setTipoPessoa(cursor.getString(4));
            cliente.setCpfCnpj(cursor.getString(5));
            cliente.getEndereco().setId(cursor.getInt(6));
            cliente.getEndereco().setTipoEnd(cursor.getString(7));
            cliente.getEndereco().setEndCliente(cursor.getString(8));
            cliente.getEndereco().setComplEnd(cursor.getString(9));
            cliente.getEndereco().setNumero(cursor.getString(10));
            cliente.getEndereco().setCep(cursor.getString(11));
            cliente.getEndereco().setIdCliente(cursor.getInt(12));
            cliente.getEndereco().setIdBairro(cursor.getInt(13));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().setId(cursor.getInt(14));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().setNome(cursor.getString(15));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().setId(cursor.getInt(16));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().setNome(cursor.getString(17));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().setCodIbge(cursor.getString(18));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().getEstado().setId(cursor.getInt(19));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().getEstado().setNome(cursor.getString(20));
            cliente.getEndereco().getBairro().getMunicipio().getEstado().setSigla(cursor.getString(21));

            cliente.setListaTelefone(getListaTelefone(cursor.getInt(0)));
            cliente.setListaEmail(getListaEmail(cursor.getInt(0)));
            cursor.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //
    }
    return cliente;
}
```

**Parte onde faço a adaptação da lista no ListView:**

```
ArrayList<Cliente> listaView = dao.getClienteByCpfCnpj2();
listaClienteCons = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lstClienteCons);
listaClienteCons.setAdapter(new ClienteConsBaseAdapter(this, listaView));
```

Comment: Esses dois métodos seus estão na mesma classe?

Answer (score 0):

A condição usada no `while(cursor.isLast())` retorna `false` logo na primeira execução, pois o cursor não está na ultima posição.

Para que funcione o resultado do teste terá de ser negado: `while(!cursor.isLast())`.

Em alternativa a `cursor.isLast()` sugiro que use `cursor.moveToNext()` no teste,  ele além de mover o cursor para a próxima posição retornará `false` quando chegar ao fim:

```
cursor = database.query(CriaBanco.TABELA_CLIENTE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
if(cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
    do{
        cliente = getClienteById(cursor.getInt(0));
        cliente.setLinha1(cliente.getNome());
        lista.add(cliente);
        int a = cursor.getPosition();
        int b = cursor.getCount();
    }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

É também aconselhável testar se o cursor não é nulo.

Comment: Ola, bom dia ramaral, fiz como sugeriu, porém persiste o mesmo erro, no moveToNext ele está indo da posição 0 para a 3

Comment: Não percebo porquê. A não ser que `int b = cursor.getCount();` mova o cursor para o fim. Elimine essa linha.

Comment: Já eliminei, tinha colocado somente para debugar e ver o que poderia ser, o estranho é que se uso outra tabela funciona perfeitamente, porém já recriei o banco e persiste o erro, pensei ser o parametros porém as constantes estão todas OK.

Comment: Não sei o que dizer. A forma do *do/while* que eu postei é a forma mais usual de percorrer um cursor. Portanto o problema não está nele.